Quadrature on an interval $[0,h]$ for $f\in C^3$ vanishing at zero
Cross-posted at Computational Science SE
I am studying for an exam and I would like to verify my solution to a past problem on numerical integration. The question is as follows.

A quadrature method has the form $\int_0^h f(x) d x \approx a f(h /
> 2)+b f(h)$.
(a) Determine $a$ and $b$ such that the method is exact
for the highest degree polynomial $p(x)=f(x)$ with the constraint
$f(0)=p(0)=0$.
(b) Give an error estimate for the approximation if $f
> \in C^3, f(0)=0$.
(c) Describe how Richardson extrapolation can be
used for an error estimate and to enhance the accuracy.

Part A
Since $p(x)=0$, we want to consider a quadratic polynomial $tx+rx^2$ since it is the lowest degree polynomial with two free parameters vanishing at zero. We compute that
$$\int_0^h p(x)\,dx = t\frac{1}{2}h^2 + r\frac{1}{3}h^3$$
and
$$af(h/2)+bf(h)=t(ah/2+bh) + r(ah^2/4 +bh^2).$$
Equating coefficients, we find that $a=2h/3, b=h/6$.
Part B
We use that we can write $f(x)= f'(0)x +\frac{1}{2}x^2f''(0)+\frac{1}{6} f'''(\xi(x))x^3$for some $\xi(x)\in[0,h]$. The quadrature formula is exact for the quadratic part of $f$, hence the error is
$$\frac{1}{6}\int_0^h f'''(\xi(x))x^3\,dx + (2h/3)\frac{1}{6}(h/2)^3f'''(h/2) + \frac{h}{6}h^3 f'''(h),$$
which is bounded above in magnitude by the triangle inequality by $C h^4 \| f'''\|_{L^\infty(0,h)}.$ for some fixed $C>0$.
Part C
If we have an asymptotic expansion for an integral $I(h)$ of the following form, with $a_0$ the estimate and the rest as error terms,
$$I(h)=a_0 + h^2a_2 + h^4 a_2 + \ldots,$$
Richardson extrapolation consists of first computing
$$I_2(h)=\frac{4I(h/2)-I(h)}{3}a=a_0+O(h^4).$$
Notice that now the error is of order $h^4$ instead of $h^2$, an improvement of $h^2$. The procedure can be repeated to obtain an error of $h^{2N}$ for any positive integer $N$.
Beyond the correctness of the calculations, I am also interested in whether there are more efficient or different ways of solving this problem.

How did you get the error bound? The quadrature is obviously Simpson for the nodes $0,2,h$, reduced to the case $f(0)=0$ which has the local error $O(h^5)$. So all your $O(h^4)$ estimates are suspect, the quadrature for $f(x)=x^3$ should also be exact. Please explain how the Richardson formalism should work, as the condition of the first node value being zero can not be applied to the second sub-interval.

I computed the error by using the fact that for a quadratic polynomial, the quadrature is exact. I agree that this is Simpson, but Simpson relies on $f\in C^4$, which is not the case here, therefore it seems we must terminate the Taylor expansion at the third derivative.

Yes, my error, of course the approximation can not be better than the input quality. But then that also restricts the usefulness of Richardson extrapolation or any other order-increasing trick. Still, while the error formula goes into the right direction, there still remain sign and midpoint questions to be corrected.

Can you let me know your remaining doubts are? I believe the question for Richardson interpolation is just looking for the general idea, and not necessarily applying it to this specific case. Indeed, you would likely need a higher degree of smoothness.

Judging by what you have presented here, you are at some midpoint between guessing and a satisfying answer. It seems as if you want to give a concrete error bound, but for that you need to clean up and finish your approach. It might be necessary to step back and try a different approach to the error formula. If you do not care about the (best) coefficients you could go more directly to an upper bound on the 3rd derivative.

Yes I am interested in getting a concrete error bound. How do you suggest I got about it?
